# Adding declaration of directive in bootstrap method

Tags: angular

I am following this tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html for creating an attribute directive in an angular 2 project. The final step for making it work is adding the directive name in the array of declarations in @NgModule. However in my own project I don't have an @NgModule, I use this method:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    listOfProviders
]);
```

And the bootstrap method doesn't except declarations, only providers. WHere should I add the declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
.....
import { provide, PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
.....

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ListOfProviders..., provide(PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, { useValue: [ListOfDirectives here....], multi: true })]);
```